# search in maps dart2 , same as list.indexOf?

Tags: dart, dart-2

I Use this sample for search in Map but not work :|:

```
  var xmenList = ['4','xmen','4xmen','test'];
  var xmenObj = {
  'first': '4',
  'second': 'xmen',
  'fifth': '4xmen',
   'author': 'test'
  };

  print(xmenList.indexOf('4xmen')); // 2
  print(xmenObj.indexOf('4xmen')); // ?
```

but I have error `TypeError: xmenObj.indexOf$1 is not a function` on last code line.

Pelease help me to **search** in **map** object simple way same as `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
 print(xmenObj.values.toList().indexOf('4xmen')); // 2
```

or this:

```
  var ind = xmenObj.values.toList().indexOf('4xmen') ;
  print(xmenObj.keys.toList()[ind]); // fifth
```

Comment: You can't assume that the order of  the keys and values is the same. In your 2nd example if `xmenObj.keys.toList()[ind]` returns the correct key, it will only be by luck.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Luck? are you kidding me ? but this answer right for my work :)

Comment: yes, pure luck. You base your solution on an assumption that is not guaranteed to be true.

Comment: Actually, the Dart `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` do promise that iterating values is equivalent to iterating keys and looking up the corresponding value. As long as the map *doesn't change* between iterations, we also promise that the iteration order is stable. That's only something we can guarantee for platform library maps, obviously, but it's recommended in general.

Answer (score 0):

Maps are not indexable by integers, so there is no operation corresponding to `indexOf`. If you see lists as specialized maps where the keys are always consecutive integers, then the corresponding operation should find the *key* for a given value.
Maps are not built for that, so iterating through all the keys and values is the only way to get that result.
I'd do that as:

```
K keyForValue<K, V>(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
  for (var entry in map.entries) {
    if (entry.value == value) return key;
  }
  return null;
}
```

The `entries` getter is introduced in Dart 2. If you don't have that, then using the `map.values.toList().indexOf(value)` to get the iteration position, and then `map.keys.elementAt(thatIndex)` to get the corresponding key.

If you really only want the numerical index, then you can skip that last step.
It's not amazingly efficient (you allocate a new list and copy all the values). Another approach is:

```
int indexOfValue<V>(Map<Object, V> map, V value) {
  int i = 0;
  for (var mapValue in map.values) {
    if (mapValue == value) return i;
    i++;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: It's too complex I needed simple way and I found this.

Answer (score 0):

You can search using `.where(...)` if you want to find all that match or `firstWhere` if you assume there can only be one or you only want the first

```
var found = xmenObj.keys.firstWhere(
    (k) => xmenObj[k] == '4xmen', orElse: () => null);
print(xmenObj[found]);
```

Comment: You are wrong ,its not simple :|, I just say need simple way not complex way.